# How to manipulate an instance of a class which contains a `unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have got a structure which looks like this:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> left = nullptr, right = nullptr;
};
```

I guess it is better to use `unique_ptr` than `shared_ptr` for a tree implentation like this, right?

Then I put a few nodes in a `priority_queue`, for example like this:

```
bool operator<(const TreeNode& t1, const TreeNode& t2)
{
    return t1.value < t2.value;
}
```

...

```
std::priority_queue<TreeNode> nodes;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode node;
    node.value = i;
    nodes.push(node);
}
```

And after that, problems with `unique_ptr` come when I have to do something like this:

```
TreeNode n1 = nodes.top();
nodes.pop();
TreeNode n2 = nodes.top();
nodes.pop();

TreeNode node;
node.value = n1.value * n2.value;
node.left = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(n1));
node.right = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(n2));
```

This code obviously doesn't work but I would like to know how I could make it work as simply as possible.

I managed to do something with a `make_unique` implementation I got from the Internet but it was too makeshift. I also tried using `std::move` and `std::forward` but without success.

Besides, I have to do something like this later:

```
std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> root(new HuffmanTreeNode(my_root));

std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> current_node = node;

while(current_node)
{
    current_node = current_node->left;
}
```

Here again, it obviously doesn't work but I don't know how to make it work properly. (The algorithm is also nonsense, it is just to explain my problem)

Can you give me an example by showing me how it could be done here? Maybe there is somehow a way to convert the `unique_ptr` into a `shared_ptr` and then the reverse operation?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, end of story. If you want to make your structure copyable then you can't use `std::unique_ptr`. Or you need to think of another design that doesn't need to copy your structure.

Comment: True, that is not really what I want to do. I modified my title. I guess it wouldn't be okay to implement the tree structure with `shared_ptr` but I guess there is still a way to do the operations I need to do.

Comment: It depends whether nodes you want to put in the queue are attached to a tree or not. If not, you may want to have a `priority_queue<unique_ptr<TreeNode>>`, or separate tree data from a tree node and have a `priority_queue<TreeData>`.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeNode` does not have a copy constructor (because the implicit one would be ill-formed, since `left` and `right` aren't copyable) but it does have an implicit move constructor, which will move `left` and `right` into the new object.  You have a few places where you attempt copies:

```
std::priority_queue<TreeNode> nodes;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode node;
    node.value = i;
    nodes.push(node); // Attempts copy of node
}

// ...

TreeNode n1 = nodes.top(); // Attempts copy of nodes.top()
nodes.pop();
TreeNode n2 = nodes.top(); // Attempts copy of nodes.top()
nodes.pop();

TreeNode node;
node.value = n1.value * n2.value;
// The following two lines attempt to copy n1 and n2, respectively.
node.left = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(n1));
node.right = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(n2));
```

There are a few other places in the following code as well, but you get the point.

Note that you can `std::move()` your own nodes to resolve the errors:

```
std::priority_queue<TreeNode> nodes;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TreeNode node;
    node.value = i;
    // Use emplace to directly-construct the element in the queue.
    nodes.emplace(std::move(node));
}

// ...

// priority_queue<T>::top() gives us a const reference; we have to cast
// the const-ness away (which is legal in this case) to move from it.
// See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20149745/501250
TreeNode n1{std::move(const_cast<TreeNode &>(nodes.top()))};
nodes.pop();
TreeNode n2{std::move(const_cast<TreeNode &>(nodes.top()))};
nodes.pop();

TreeNode node;
node.value = n1.value * n2.value;
node.left = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(std::move(n1)));
node.right = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>(new TreeNode(std::move(n2)));
```

Comment: Also `TreeNode* current_node = node.get();`

Comment: Yeah, I left that block alone because I'm not 100% sure what it's trying to accomplish. I corrected the obvious copies in the first two blocks hoping that would give OP enough of a nudge in the right direction to understand the problem and solution, and hopefully they can apply that themselves to the rest of their code.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I have a few questions though: although `nodes.push(node)` makes a copy of `node`, the `std::unique_ptr` are `nullptr` here so it doesn't produce an error. How is it better? Then about the `const_cast`, I understand the 'legal' aspect, but what happens to the `nodes.top()` element after it's moved out? We still need to pop it so is it still here but without the pointers? Also about the `TreeNode* current_node = node.get();`, why should we rather use a raw pointer here?

Comment: @Yksuh You can't copy an `std::unique_ptr` at all, regardless of whether it contains an object -- it has no copy constructor, period. After the `nodes.top()` object is moved from, its `left` and `right` members point to `nullptr`. Correct, moving from an object doesn't destroy the object, it "steals" the object's contents. I suspect that you want to use a raw pointer because `std::unique_ptr` is an *owning* pointer that will delete its contents when it goes out of scope. Taking a raw pointer from a unique_ptr effectively "borrows" a non-owning copy of the pointer.